# do equations survive transition to docx and pptx?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, equation-editor

I have doc and ppt files with equations in them created by Equation Editor. I created the files in Microsoft Office X for Mac Service Release 1. I am thinking of switching to Office Mac 2008 as that is what most of my students use. What will happen to the equations?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, equations created in Word 2007's equation editor get turned into un-editable graphics in PowerPoint 2007; this was fixed in Office 2010.

I imagine the OSX versions of Office around that time fixed the problem too, so for your question: "likely depends on version number."